# How do I override a function of a python library?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a python library where I need to override one of the functions. Let's call this `module.py`:

```
def dump(nodes, args = 'bleh' ):
  ...validation checks
  for node in nodes:
    print(node, someother_args)

def print_node(node, someother_args):
  ...prints in some way i don't want
```

Now, I am using this `dump` method and I want to override the `print_node` function with my own `print_node` method because I want to print it in different way. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Note that you've tagged this with python2.7, and in 2.7 print is not a function. You can import print_function from future at the top of your file to change that (it was changed in python3 to be a function, partly for this reason)

Comment: This is doable, but almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @user2357112 The question in the title is a bad idea, but the thing paris is actually trying to do isn't, IMO. Overwriting the default function may lead to maintainability problems, but wanting a custom print function isn't bad - I'd just name it something different, e.g., print_and_log that prints and writes to a log might very-well be useful

Comment: oh I am sorry, @en_Knight you are right. It is print_node function of that library not python's default print function

Comment: What you want to do is called monkey patching. Look it up.

Comment: As I looked it up, I found monkey patching has some pitfalls. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a class by yourself that inherits from intended module, and override the function in any way you want. Then you can use your object instead of `module.py`.

```
class my_class(module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(my_class, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def dump(self):
        # do stuff
```

As you mentioned in comment if your module is contain a bunch of functions you better to define the new function in your current module. Then you can assign it to that function name.

As @Joran Beasley also mentioned, you can do something like following

```
import my_file
my_file.dump = my_local_dump_fn
```